# How to test cronjob in ruby on rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I create a cronjob in ruby on rails by using whenever gem and write a code in `schedule.rb`

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
 every '* * * * * ' do
   command "puts 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
 end
```

After that I update my crontab by command

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

and restart

```
sudo service cron restart
```

and check by `crontab -l`

> Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb
>   * * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'puts '\''you can use raw cron syntax too'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'
>
> End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb

But it doesn't work meanz cronjo doesn't work. How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

you can run your  cron job by,
ruby /home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule

Comment: are u logged in as root and also u have gone to /home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/ directory  and run ruby schedule

Comment: just one thing more that error come

/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 17: every: command not found

/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 18: puts 'you can use raw cron syntax too': command not found

/home/haseebahmad/projects/social/config/schedule.rb: line 20: end: command not found